# SciPy LeastSq Dfun Usage

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to get my Jacobian to work with SciPy's Optimize library's leastsq function.

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import scipy
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

#Define real coefficients
p_real=[3,5,1]

#Define functions
def func(p, x):         #Function
    return p[0]*numpy.exp(-p[1]*x)+p[2]

def dfunc(p, x, y):     #Derivative
    return [numpy.exp(-p[1]*x),-x*p[0]*numpy.exp(-p[1]*x), numpy.ones(len(x))]

def residuals(p, x, y):
    return y-func(p, x)

#Generate messy data
x_vals=numpy.linspace(0,10,30)
y_vals=func(p_real,x_vals)
y_messy=y_vals+numpy.random.normal(size=len(y_vals))

#Fit
plsq,cov,infodict,mesg,ier=leastsq(residuals, [10,10,10], args=(x_vals, y_vals), Dfun=dfunc, col_deriv=1, full_output=True)

print plsq
```

Now, when I run this, I get `plsq=[10,10,10]` as my return. When I take out `Dfun=dfunc, col_deriv=1`, then I get something close to `p_real`.

Can anyone tell me what gives? Or point out a better source of documentation than what SciPy provides?

Incidentally, I'm using the Jacobian because I have the (perhaps misguided) belief that it will lead to faster convergence.

Comment: It looks to me like your derivative is negative of what it should be -- because your residuals have actual-func, not func-actual.

Comment: For anyone who's interested. A similar application of the above code, fitting 5940 quadratic surfaces to 3D data described by a function z=quad(x,y), showed, on average, a 0.5-0.6 second speed-up using the Jacobian than not.

Comment: typo: y_messy not y_vals in the call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `residuals` to its negative:

```
def residuals(p, x, y):
    return func(p, x)-y
```

and you get

```
[ 3.  5.  1.]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Owen, do you know why the residuals should be arranged this way?

Comment: @Richard: in leastsq, the gradient is supposed to be the gradient of the function you're fitting -- which in this case is `residuals` -- so you want the derivative of `residuals` to be the same as the derivative of `func`.

Comment: I guess another option would be to take the negative of the gradient you have -- whichever you prefer.